# Are Popular Musicology questions likely to be better suited to MusicFan.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

If users want to gain musicological knowledge about specific works of popular music, or specific artists, or indeed be pointed towards *lists* of relevant information, do you feel this is likely to be better accommodated at the proposed MusicFans.SE, than here on Music.SE?

I have concerns that some requests for information may fall between the two sites; musicological questions may be too academic for MusicFans.SE, when this gets going, and questions about specific works, composers, artists etc. are sometimes not on topic at Music.SE (*because* they are too specific).

I am particularly interested about the popular musicology aspect of this, but musicology generally seems to raise this issue…

To put this in the simplest terms possible; where do I ask a question about a specific Beatles song?; where do I ask a question about a specific Beethoven string quartet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different questions have different goals and audiences. Questions about works in order to understand the theory behind some construction in the song fits here, questions about works similar to a piece of music would be better on Music Fans. I do think we should link to the Music Fans proposal when we close, in order to add interest for that SE.